# Language-specific setting about colorTheme in VSCode

Tags: latex, visual-studio-code

I want to set a colorTheme for each language.

For example,
Latex --> "Quiet Light",
Others --> "Dark+".

We can set each settings language-specifically.
So I added to language-specific setting like this,

```
"[latex]":{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Quiet Light"
}
```

But, the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Not as of VS Code 1.15. Only `editor.*` settings are supported in the language specific settings currently

We are tracking the feature here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/20652